# Windows 7 cmd.exe not always display colors properly

Tags: windows-7, command-line, colors

I have strange beheviour with my cmd.exe. I installed Hg few months ago and everything is OK while displaying colored Mercurial commands. Problem is that I installed also composer and PHPUnit which also allow colored output but have only plain white/black output. Did I forgot about something? At home everything works perfectly.

Comment: Could you amplify the symptoms? I cannot get a clear picture of te problem.

Comment: Problem was stupid - like me... After few days I found that at work I haven't installed ansicon - so, it wasn't a real problem but only my stupidity. Sorry for posting.

Comment: I know it's frowned upon, but sometimes I find just posting the question makes me realize what the problem is. Glad yours is sovled.